# Run configurations in maven

Tags: gwt, maven, jetty

I want to use maven to run my application in test mode. I have a multi module project which uses gwt. To debug my app I want to do the following:

- Run jetty in exploded directory
- Run gwt in a hosted mode with -noserver option

Now I have to do this manually in the IDE. Is there any way to do this automatically from maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maven, you can use the [`jetty-maven-plugin`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) to run Jetty in your *server* module (use the `start` or `run` goal), and the [`gwt-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) to launch GWT's DevMode (use the `run` or `debug` goal).

To my knowledge, you cannot however do that with a single Maven command.

Have a look at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for sample configurations of such multi-module GWT projects.